# `Class.new` returns `nil` when the class name lookup silently fails?

Tags: ruby, pry

Here is the class I'm trying to instantiate from a class method:
Note that there is no `initialize` or `new`, and that both are inherited from the `Base`

```
module Operation
  module ExampleOperation
    class Read < SkinnyControllers::Operation::Base
      def run
        model if allowed?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my pry output:

```
From: /home/me/Development/skinny_controllers/lib/skinny_controllers/operation/base.rb @ line 24 SkinnyControllers::Operation::Base.run:

    21: def self.run(current_user, params)
    22:   object = self.new(current_user, params)
    23:   binding.pry
 => 24:   object.run
    25: end

[1] pry(Operation::ExampleOperation::Read)> object
=> nil
[2] pry(Operation::ExampleOperation::Read)> self
=> Operation::ExampleOperation::Read
[3] pry(Operation::ExampleOperation::Read)> self.new
=> nil
[4] pry(Operation::ExampleOperation::Read)> Operation::ExampleOperation::Read.new
NameError: uninitialized constant SkinnyControllers::Operation::ExampleOperation
from (pry):4:in `run'

# Try the top level namespace just in case
[5] pry(Operation::ExampleOperation::Read)> ::Operation::ExampleOperation::Read.new
=> nil


# see if I can instantiate the base class
[6] pry(Operation::ExampleOperation::Read)> SkinnyControllers::Operation::Base.new(User.new, {})
=> #<SkinnyControllers::Operation::Base:0x0000000117e7a0 @authorized_via_parent=false, @current_user=#<User:0x0000000117e7f0>, @params={}>

# try instantiate via specifying the exact namespace shown in line 4
[7] pry(Operation::ExampleOperation::Read)> SkinnyControllers::Operation::ExampleOperation::Read.new(User.new, {})
NameError: uninitialized constant SkinnyControllers::Operation::ExampleOperation
from (pry):7:in `run'
```

Why is this happening?
It's really weird that `self.new` *doesn't* make an instance object..

Here is my code to see the failing test:
[at this specific commit](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/skinny_controllers/commit/fc54012e9bfa4e8e8e58e8bb4a380c6eb298e3db).

I read about the relationship between `new` and `initialize` that it shouldn't be possible. Maybe I have something funky going on between `SkinnyControllers::Operation` and the resolution of `Operation`, but I wanted to document this and gather thoughts of others.

UPDATE:

the initialize method is only defined in the super class, `Operation::Base`

```
  def initialize(current_user, params)
    self.current_user = current_user
    self.params = params
    self.authorized_via_parent = false
  end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: How does your `initialize` method look like? Did you override the `new` method?

Comment: Added the initialize method to the post. The New method has not been modified.